# Setting 'dead' area background colour in gVim

Tags: linux, vim, colors, gvim

In gVim on Linux (confirmed on Windows as well), depending on the selected font family & size and the window dimensions, sometimes a 'dead' area appears on the right and bottom of the window as shown in the screen grab attached

[image]

While the theme is configured to have a black background, the 'dead' area inherits the OS window colours (grey in this case).

Is there any way to configure this within Vim? It's very annoying in full-screen where there is no control over the window dimensions as it leaves a vertical line on the right-hand side looking very out of place.

To confirm, this is Ubuntu Precise, gVim latest from official repos.

.vimrc is available at [GitHub](https://github.com/StanAngeloff/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc), however it doesn't probably have anything to do with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[There's a simple and easy to google solution.](http://pastebin.com/N0G333nP)

Here it is, for posterity.

```
# this goes in your ~/.gtkrc-2.0 file

style "vimfix" {
  bg[NORMAL] = "#242424" # this matches my gvim theme 'Normal' bg color.
}
widget "vim-main-window.*GtkForm" style "vimfix"

# taken from a very helpful post here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=65285
```

By the way, the linked thread at the Arch forums is where I've found it a year or so ago. Their forums and their Wiki are one of the best place to find readable and up to date info on Linux.

Comment: For new versions of vim using gtk3, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39768273/695459).